# Problem with examdesign and twocolumn in Debian 8

Tags: two-column, exam, debian

I have a problem when I compile a tex document of the examdesign class, with the "twocolumn" option and have Debian-8 (Jessie) on my computer. I have the XFCE 4.10 desktop, just in case the information were relevant.

When I pdfLaTeX a tex file in Debian Jessie, examdesign and twocolumn, the resulting output has strange dimensions, like if it had to fit on a paper quite longer than a A4 paper. The output in, say, page 1 gets truncated, it runs out of paper, but then the missing text is not in page 2. It's like the system expected a different paper size on the pdf. Adding the option a4paper doesn't help.

Curiously enough, the combination examdesign+twocolumn works well with Debian-7 (Wheezy, with XFCE 4.8), with Ubuntu 14, with texlive for mac and for Windows.

Also, on Debian Jessie examdesign with just one column woks well.

On Debian Jessie too, other classes, like article, work well with one column as well as with the twocolumn option.

So it seems to be a strange combination Debian Jessie + examdesign + twocolumn

I have tested the same tex file in three systems.

- A PC with Debian-8
- A VBox on the former, with Debian-7
- A Mac, with OSX 10.8.5

Only in the first one (Debian-8) problems appeared.

The version of pdfTeX is different on all of them. We can see one more decimal place in the version on the Debian-8 system. Might this be it?

From the corresponding log files:

On Debian-8
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2015/dev/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2014.12.11)  19 JAN 2015 13:55

On Debian 7
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012/Debian) (format=pdflatex 2015.1.9)  19 JAN 2015 14:06

On Mac
This is pdfTeXk, Version 3.1415926-1.40.9 (Web2C 7.5.7) (format=pdflatex 2009.10.4)  19 JAN 2015 14:01

Below is the tex file producing the aforementioned results. It's rather long, since I want several pages produced. It is a twenty question test, all the questions being equal.

Many thanks

Antonio

```
%\documentclass[12pt]{examdesign}
\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn]{examdesign}

\setlength{\textwidth}{17cm} \setlength{\textheight}{25cm}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{2cm} \setlength{\hoffset}{-3cm}
\setlength{\voffset}{-2cm}

\NoRearrange

%\setrandomseed
%\ContinuousNumbering

\DefineAnswerWrapper{}{} 
\NumberOfVersions{1}

\ShortKey
%\OneKey
%\NoKey

\begin{document}

\begin{examtop}
\begin{center}
\textbf{\Large{Title exam}}\qquad

\textbf{\Large{TYPE }}:~\fbox{\Huge{\textsf{\arabic{version}}}}
\end{center}
\end{examtop}

\begin{keytop}
\begin{center}
\textbf{\Large{Title exam}}\qquad
%\examtype,
\Large{\textbf{TYPE}}:~\fbox{\Huge{\textsf{\arabic{version}}}}
\end{center}
\end{keytop}

\begin{multiplechoice}

\begin{question}
Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. 

\choice{First choice}
\choice{Second choice}
\choice[!]{Third choice}
\choice{Forth choice}
\end{question}

\begin{question}
Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. 

\choice{First choice}
\choice{Second choice}
\choice[!]{Third choice}
\choice{Forth choice}
\end{question}

\begin{question}
Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. 

\choice{First choice}
\choice{Second choice}
\choice[!]{Third choice}
\choice{Forth choice}
\end{question}

\begin{question}
Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. 

\choice{First choice}
\choice{Second choice}
\choice[!]{Third choice}
\choice{Forth choice}
\end{question}

\begin{question}
Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. 

\choice{First choice}
\choice{Second choice}
\choice[!]{Third choice}
\choice{Forth choice}
\end{question}

\begin{question}
Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. 

\choice{First choice}
\choice{Second choice}
\choice[!]{Third choice}
\choice{Forth choice}
\end{question}

\begin{question}
Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. 

\choice{First choice}
\choice{Second choice}
\choice[!]{Third choice}
\choice{Forth choice}
\end{question}

\begin{question}
Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. 

\choice{First choice}
\choice{Second choice}
\choice[!]{Third choice}
\choice{Forth choice}
\end{question}

\begin{question}
Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. 

\choice{First choice}
\choice{Second choice}
\choice[!]{Third choice}
\choice{Forth choice}
\end{question}

\begin{question}
Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. 

\choice{First choice}
\choice{Second choice}
\choice[!]{Third choice}
\choice{Forth choice}
\end{question}

\begin{question}
Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. 

\choice{First choice}
\choice{Second choice}
\choice[!]{Third choice}
\choice{Forth choice}
\end{question}

\begin{question}
Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. 

\choice{First choice}
\choice{Second choice}
\choice[!]{Third choice}
\choice{Forth choice}
\end{question}

\begin{question}
Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. 

\choice{First choice}
\choice{Second choice}
\choice[!]{Third choice}
\choice{Forth choice}
\end{question}

\begin{question}
Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. 

\choice{First choice}
\choice{Second choice}
\choice[!]{Third choice}
\choice{Forth choice}
\end{question}

\begin{question}
Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. 

\choice{First choice}
\choice{Second choice}
\choice[!]{Third choice}
\choice{Forth choice}
\end{question}

\begin{question}
Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. 

\choice{First choice}
\choice{Second choice}
\choice[!]{Third choice}
\choice{Forth choice}
\end{question}

\begin{question}
Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. 

\choice{First choice}
\choice{Second choice}
\choice[!]{Third choice}
\choice{Forth choice}
\end{question}

\begin{question}
Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. 

\choice{First choice}
\choice{Second choice}
\choice[!]{Third choice}
\choice{Forth choice}
\end{question}

\begin{question}
Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. 

\choice{First choice}
\choice{Second choice}
\choice[!]{Third choice}
\choice{Forth choice}
\end{question}

\begin{question}
Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. Question statement. 

\choice{First choice}
\choice{Second choice}
\choice[!]{Third choice}
\choice{Forth choice}
\end{question}

\end{multiplechoice}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Is there a difference in the TeXLive versions?

Comment: Thanks Christian and Kurt for your answers. I will get to my machine in one or two days and provide the information you are requesting.

Comment: Dear Christian and Kurt, I have edited my question including an example file. Thanks, Antonio

Comment: I believe there is a conflict between (1) the `twopage` option, (2) the package's internal use of the `multicol` package, and (3) the way the package bundles and outputs questions as a block. I don't think the operating system information is relevant, though it's always better to use an up-to-date TeXLive installation direct from TUG instead of using Debian's very old repository packages.

Comment: Consider using the `geometry` package to adjust the page dimensions instead of doing it manually. Also, you might wrap some of your formatting in macros: `\newcommand{\examtitlefont}{\Large\bfseries} \newcommand{\versionbox}{\fbox{\Huge\textsf{\arabix{version}}}}`

Comment: Thanks to you all. I have tried the example on another systems. A Xubuntu 14.04, which install texlive 2013. It compiles well. So, it seems that until texlive 2013 all goes well, the problemm seems to be in texlive 2014.

Comment: Andrew, as for the geometry package, I understand that there are problems of compatibility with the twocolumn option. I tried once and examdesign+twocolum+geometry puts all the output in the left half of the page.

Comment: I have tested the above exameple on still another, and final, TeX system. On a Windows-7 machine, Texlive 2014, pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2014/W32TeX), the pages are truncated as described above. So I think that we can identify the bug as a problem on Texlive 2014, since in versions 2009, 2012 and 2013 on different operating systems it does not appear. I will try to contact the developer and post again only if I get new information. Do you know if this package is currently mantained (January 2015)?

Comment: Any news on this? Some workaround? I have exactly the same problem. Still keeping a Debian 7 system in a laptop to format examdesign + twocolumn documents.

Comment: @F.Tusell What's really needed is a list of the files involved: it's not 'TeX Live' that causes such issues but particularly package changes. Adding `\listfiles` to the input will give a file list in the `.log` file: versions of this for the two set ups would be ideal.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I have done as directed, and I think  the problem can be traced to package 'multicol'. It complains that it may not work with twocolumn option in input line; but so did the old multicol, and it worked perfectly. The log files with both Debian 8 (doesn't work) and Debian 7 (works all right) are in http://www.et.bs.ehu.es/~etptupaf/Examproblem . Don't really know where to go from here, perhaps a solution would be to grab an old version of multicol and keep it locally so as to override the system wide new multicol. Your advice welcome.